# Sqlite3 not committing as expected when inserting

Tags: python, sqlite

So as the title describes, python is not committing to the database even if I ask it to

The following code is the one I use for inserting into the database:

```
try:
    get_db().execute("insert into Profesor(DNI, NombreApellidos, Telefono, Email, Ranking) values(?,?,?,?,?)", [dni, nombre, telefono, email, ranking])
    get_db().commit()
    get_db().close()
    return "OK"

except:
    return "Algo ha fallado insertando los datos, intentelo de nuevo"
```

get_db() is a function that does the connection with:

```
def get_db():
    db = sqlite3.connect("database.db) 
    return db
```

Unfortunately, every time I check the table, it doesn't return with the result committed, not through my python function nor from the terminal. But if I insert the data above through the terminal, it works fine, when I check from the command line it shows the new added data and my python function displays the new added data also.

The only solution I found so far is adding *isolation_level=None* when connecting

What am I doing wrong so far? :(

Comment: `get_db()` returns a new connection each time you call it, so the `.execute()` call is not operating on the same connection as the `.commit()` call.  Call get_db _only once_ and reuse that connection for all the operations.

Comment: Oh so dumb of me! Didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

As @John Gordon rightly pointed, this was caused because I was opening a new connection every time I was calling get_db(). Solved with the solution he proposed